# Change the class of columns in a list of data frames

Tags: r, class

I have a list of data frames, e.g.

```
df1 = data.frame(ID=c("id1", "id2", "id3"), A1 = c("A", "A", "B"), A2 = c("AA", "AA", "AA"))
df2 = data.frame(ID=c("id2", "id3", "id4"), A1 = c("B", "B", "B"), A2=c("BB", "BB", "BB"))
df3 = data.frame(ID=c("id1", "id2", "id3"), A1 = c("A", "A", "A"), A2 = c("AA", "BB", "BB"))
listDF = list(df1, df2, df3)
```

I am wondering if there is a good way to change the class from factor to character. This is what I have tried:

```
d <- lapply(listDF, function(x) sapply(x[,"A1", "A2"], as.character))
```

This code gives me the columns I want to change, but is there a way to just change the class and not have to re-append these new columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mutate_at()` function from `dplyr` package comes handy here:

```
library(dplyr)
d <- lapply(listDF, function(df) mutate_at(df, .cols = 2:3, as.character))
```

You can also pass the column names to `.cols` parameter:

```
d <- lapply(listDF, function(df) mutate_at(df, .cols = c("A1", "A2"), as.character))
```

Or select the columns by regex:

```
# mutate columns whose names start with A
d <- lapply(listDF, function(df) mutate_at(df, vars(matches("^A")), as.character))
```

---

In base R, this could be:

```
d <- lapply(listDF, function(df) {df[c("A1", "A2")] <- lapply(df[c("A1", "A2")], as.character); df})
```

Comment: Thank you Psidom, it works, although I was hoping there could be a solution in base R without adding a function...

Comment: It can be done in base R pretty easily also. See the updates!

Comment: Ah great!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Perhaps `listDF %>% map(. %>% mutate_at(2:3, as.character))` more in line with tidyverse

Comment: I am trying this code but does not work for me. Class for column A1 still shows as factor. `d <- lapply(listDF, function(df) mutate_at(df, vars(matches("^A")), as.character))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
lapply(listDF, function(df) setDT(df)[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = 2:3])
```

Comment: Why do I still see column class as factor after using this code? Do I need to assign it back to the dataframe somehow? `listDF <- lapply(listDF, function(df) setDT(df)[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = 2:3])`

Comment: @MattGossett yes, you can assign it to `listDF`

Answer (score 0):

The `list.update` function from `rlist` package provides a handy alternative.

```
  names(listDF) <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")
  d <- list.update(listDF,A1 = as.factor(A1), A2 = as.factor(A2))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`, you can use a combination of `purrr` and `across` inside `mutate` to change particular columns in each dataframe in the list. Here, I use `starts_with`, but you can also supply the names too (i.e., `c(A1, A2)`).

```
library(tidyverse)

map(listDF, ~ .x %>%
      mutate(across(starts_with("A"), as.character)))
```